# Convergence in probability implies convergence almost surely for double sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove the following statement:

**Proposition.** If $X_{n,m}\to X$ in probability then there exist a subsequence $X_{k_n, l_m}$ of $X_{n,m}$ such that $X_{k_n,l_m}\to X$ almost surely.

Note: By double subsequence I mean two strictly increasing sequences of natural numbers $k_n$ and $l_m$ and by convergence of a double sequence I mean convergence as $n,m\to\infty$ jointly.

This is a well-known result for single sequences. Am not sure it holds for double sequences because the Borel-Cantelli lemma dosen't seem adaptable to double sequences.

However I think it is possible to prove the weaker result that there exist a subsequence $X_{k_n, l_n}$ of $X_{n,m}$ such that $X_{k_n,l_n}\to X$ almost surely. The difference here is that the double sequence $X_{k_n, l_n}$ is now regarded as a single sequence with single index $n$.

Is my reasoning correct? And what about the converse statement that $X_{n,m}\to X$ almost surely implies $X_{n,m}\to X$ in probability?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist integers $N_k$ such that $P(|X_{nm}-X|>\frac  1 {2^{k}}) <\frac  1 {2^{k}}$ whenever $n,m \geq N_k$ (and in particular for $n=m=N_k$) and we may suppose that $N_k$ is increasing. It follows by Borel Cantelli Lemma that  $X_{N_k,N_k} \to X$ almost surely.
The converse follows immediately from the following elementary fact:

Let $(a_{nm}) \subset \mathbb R$ and $a \in \mathbb R$ . Then $a_{nm} \to a$ as $n,m \to \infty$ iff $a_{n_k,m_k} \to a$ for any two sequence $(n_k),(m_k)$ increasing t $\infty$.

Comment: Exactly! So only the weaker result holds right? And what about the converse?

Comment: @Alphie  Converse is also true. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Not sure how the converse follows from this. You mean using the result for single random sequences ?

Comment: Convergence in probability is convergence of a sequence of numbers. Apply the lemma for this sequence.

Comment: Convergence in probability is convergence of a sequence of numbers. Apply the lemma for this sequence.

Comment: Am confused. Your lemma is for deterministic sequences. Convergence in probability applies to random sequences.

Comment: It is true that $X_{n,m}\to X$ in probability if and only if for any two strictly increasing sequences of natural numbers $(n_k)$ and $(m_k)$ we have $X_{n_k,m_k} \to X$ in probability.

Comment: So now the question is reduced to a single sequence instead of a double sequence.